# How to nest an else if statement in PHP or is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

So my code is partially working. I'm able to call to the correct category ID and pull the correct image BUT when I go to the next page in the pagination the category images don't show until I hit refresh. I don't think I'm doing my nested if else statements correctly I've tried various combinations to no avail. I'm trying to assign featured images based on event category if that event doesn't have a set featured image. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Featured Image for Certain Event Categories
function my_default_featured_images() {
    global $post;
    $featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

    if ($attached_image) {
        foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
            }
        }
// Identify the category this should apply to.
    else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) {
        if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'charity-fundraising' ) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32766' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default


    } else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) {
        } if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'trunk-shows' ) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32768' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default


    } else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) {     
        } if  ( tribe_event_in_category( 'performing-arts' ) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32828' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default
            wp_reset_postdata();}

            }}}


add_action('the_post', 'my_default_featured_images');
```

This is my updated code that is now getting syntax errors before second, third else if statements. I'm still learning propper syntax so I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
 // Featured Image for Certain Event Categories
function my_default_featured_images() {
    global $post;
    $featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

    if ($attached_image) {
        foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
            wp_reset_postdata;
            }
        }
// Identify the category this should apply to.
    else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) 
         if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'charity-fundraising' ) ) 
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32766' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default

   } else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) )
         if  ( tribe_event_in_category( 'trunk-shows' ) )
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32768' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default


   else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) 
         if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'performing-arts' ) ) 
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32828' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default


}

add_action('the_post', 'my_default_featured_images');
```

Comment: 1. The second `{` after the `else if`s closing your condition... please edit your code.

  2. Please try to `wp_reset_postdata();` at the first `foreach` loop as well.

Comment: I think this is what you meant. I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing syntax:

```php
 // Featured Image for Certain Event Categories
function my_default_featured_images() {
    global $post;
    $featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );
    }

    if ($attached_image) {
        foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
           set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); // This is a function so theres a need for ()
     }
    // Identify the category this should apply to.
    else if ( tribe_is_event( $post->ID ) ) { // Adding '{' at the end of condition
         if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'charity-fundraising' ) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32766' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default
         } // End if 'charity-fundraising'

         else if  ( tribe_event_in_category( 'trunk-shows' ) ){ // Removed another if tribe_is_event. instead - if/else for tribe_event_in_cat 
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32768' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default
         } // End if 'trunk-shows'

         else if ( tribe_event_in_category( 'performing-arts' ) ) {
            set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, '32828' ); // Change '0000' to the ID of whatever image you want as a default
         } // End if 'performing-arts'

    } //End if tribe is event

}

add_action('the_post', 'my_default_featured_images');
```

Comment: The syntax didn't validate in visual studio code and I added a } before add_action and it breaks the website when added to functions.php.

Comment: @Mike I just edited that. I was missing a } for the closing `!featured_image_exists` condition